# Symlink to static html page Django

Tags: django, symlink

Does anyone know how to symlink using django? I have added sphinx documentation to my django project but as it is not a django package itself so i cannot link it us using the usual django framework. My Boss told me to copy/symlink it into the static folder in a help directory then it will be available through /static/help/ but i have no idea how to do that and online information is sketchy at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Symlinking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) is a file system feature that allows you to create shortcuts from one path to another. It doesn't have anything specifically to do with django.

Because your webserver is serving the contents of your `STATIC_ROOT` folder, you can just symlink sphinx build folder to a path in your static folder and your webserver will serve it.

Do do so (assuming you are on ubuntu or similar):

```
ln -s /path/to/existing/sphink/build/ /path/to/django/static/folder/help/
```